# Most efficient way to play ticking sound at intervals correlated to velocity?

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I have a ball that has sharp edges, and I want to simulate clicking when the ball rolls. How would I go about playing a ticking sound at an interval that correlates with the velocity of the ball? Ex. as the ball velocity increases, the ticking becomes more frequent.

Current variables available:

```
AudioClip[] tickSounds;   // the sound files
bool onGround;            // indicates if the ball is on the ground
Rigidbody rb;             // Rigidbody of the ball to access velocity
```

I have tried `Time.frameCount` and modulation, but I couldn't get a good rhythm going.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! Use Coroutines!

```
void Start() {
    StartCoroutines("TickSound", 30f);    // method name, initial wait time
}

IEnumerator TickSound(float time) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);
    while (true) {
        // Don't bother playing sounds if its below a certain velocity
        if (onGround && rb.velocity.magnitude > 1f) {
            au.PlayOneShot(tickSounds[Random.Range(0, tickSounds.Length)], 0.2f);
        }
        // Used this equation 0.6f / ((velocity / 3f) + 1)
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.6f / (rb.velocity.magnitude / 3f + 1)) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if your answer works, I'd recommend using a `float timer;` variable to store time and use `timer += Time.deltaTime;` in `Update()`. If your `timer` value is `> 0.6f / (rb.velocity.magnitude / 3f + 1)`, you reset it to 0 and play your sound. This way you avoid having an infinite Coroutine running.